# Unable to use UX Studio with java7 - upgrade to java8 not neccessary

Tags: java, eclipse, demandware

After latest Demandware update I couldn't work with UX Studio anymore. I have found that java8 is now required.

Since I don't want to install java8, is it any way to make it work with java 7?

Comment: You should post a question, and then answer it. Now you seem to have posted an answer as a question.

Comment: Ok, I corrected that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just want to share one way to overcome this problem if you can't install Java 8 on your machine.

Since this occurs only because SSL certificate are switched to TLS1.1 you could still use Java 7, just one file should be copied from Java 8.

Replace the default trusted keystore file - cacerts, with the one from java 8. This is how it can be done:

1. Locate file named "cacerts" inside Java 7 lib directory,
2. Rename it ( for a backup ),
3. find the file with the same name used by Java 8,
4. copy the file found in Java 8 to Java 7

This method doesn't necessarily mean you need to install Java 8. You just need to find the file cacerts which can be copied from a machine that has it installed, or you can unpack the downloaded archive. It is the fastest way to solve this issue. I have just tested this and it works.